# How to create form which will show fields from two models?

Tags: python, django

I have two models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="name", max_length=40)
    cost = models.FloatField(verbose_name="price")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Shop(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nazwa", max_length=40)
    budget = models.FloatField(verbose_name="kwota")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I created a form

code:

```
class ShopForm(forms.ModelForm): 
        product = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = Product.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),required=True) 
        name = forms.CharField(max_length=15, label='Name')
        budget = forms.FloatField()

        class Meta: 
                model = Shop
                fields = ('product','name', 'budget')
```

[image]

It looks like on this picture, i don't know how can i show next to name of products their price? For example:
hehe - 12$

Now i have only name, i want get cost from model "Product", anybody know how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this in different ways:

- make changes in `__unicode__` method in your model

  ```
  class Product(models.Model):
      ...
      def __unicode__(self):
          return u"{}({})".format(self.name, self.cost)
  ```
- override init method in form

  ```
   class ShopForm(forms.ModelForm):
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(ShopForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           self.fields['product'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: u"%s | %s" % (obj.name, obj.cost)
  ```
- create custom form field:

  ```
  from django.forms.models import ModelMultipleChoiceField

  class ProductModelChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):

      def label_from_instance(self, obj):
          return u"%s | %s" % (obj.name, obj.cost)
  ```